# Software for server monitoring with REST API

Tags: linux, monitoring, api, web-server, system-monitor

I am planning to build custom autoscaling logic for DigitalOcean using their API. I have seen [DigitalOcean Elasticity](https://github.com/sergiovilar/digitalocean-elasticity) project, but I need a more flexible solution.

The idea is to have a 'master' server, that works as load balancer and also monitors 'slave' servers across which it distributes the load. So that 'master' server will decide whether to start a new droplet (DigitalOcean server) or destroy the existing one.

The thing is, this 'master' server needs a way to receive system resources utilization data from 'slave' servers. So I am looking for a software (for Linux) that gathers this data (CPU and RAM usage; instant values and averages) and exposes it with a REST API, so 'master' server can get the data using this API. This tool should preferably have authentication, so the data is only accessible with the valid token.

Comment: Why do you need a REST-API. Does your server not support ssh calls? How do you start and stop Nodes?